# Passing an instance to an instance method makes a reference to that instance method?

Tags: ios, swift, instance

In *iOS 13 Programming Fundamentals with Swift* by Matt Neuburg I came across this strange bit of code

```
class MyClass {
    var s = ""
    func store(_ s:String) {
        self.s = s
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let m = MyClass()
        let f = MyClass.store(m) // what just happened!?
        f("howdy")
        print(m.s) // howdy
    }

}
```

Apparently f has the type `() -> ()` (thats what it says on debugger at least) and yet on the next line we are passing a string to it.

Based of the result it seems that f has somehow become a reference to the store method which is why when `m.s` is printed you get "howdy". But this code really baffles me and an explanation of what is going on would be much appreciated.

I don't even understand how `MyClass.store` is legal because `store` is an instance method and in this case it is being referred to as if it was a static method.

Comment: I haven't seen this before but you assign a function to a variable and you also say what instance the function (since it is an instance function) should be executed on. So 'm' is an instance of `MyClass` and `f` is a variable for executing the `store` function on `m`. And notice that the full syntax of `MyClass.store` is `MyClass.store(self: MyClass). In the same way your view controller has `ViewController.viewDidLoad(self: ViewController)`

Comment: But maybe @matt can help us out here :)

Answer (score 3):

The next words in the book tell you the answer:

> The reason is that an instance method is actually a curried static/class method composed of two functions — one function that takes an instance, and another function that takes the parameters of the instance method. After that code, `f` is the *second* of those functions, and can be called as a way of passing a parameter to the `store` method *of the instance `m`.*

Comment: Ah I see. Sorry, despite what I said in the question, I saw this in the xcode projects not the book (I use them in tandem). I'll finish chapter before asking question next time.

Comment: Yes, the code is "just the code". It's intended to go with the narration in the book! Sometimes it's useful without the book, and sometimes there will even be some code that didn't make it into the book (I usually call that out, though perhaps not always), but in general it is meant to be merely the runnable version of what it says in the book. The book teaches; the code lets you try it for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Any instance method in Swift can also be called statically, but if you do that you need to pass it an instance to operate on. So, for example, you could choose to sort an array like this:

`let sortedArray = Array.sort([13, 8, 21, 3, 1, 34, 5, 1, 2])`

So, while the instance method is defined as `store(_ s: String)`, the compiler is also implicitly creating a static variant of the method that’s more like `static func store(_ self: MyClass) -> ((String)->())`. I’m not sure why the debugger would tell you f is `()->()` - that sounds like Xcode hijinks and shenanigans.

This property of Swift has some pretty cool uses, though. See https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/first-class-functions-in-swift